# Convert subquery to join query

Tags: mysql, sql

this is the working MySQL query, is it possible to convert this into single flat join query to increase performance ? Rather than using sub-query below. Thanks

```
SELECT * from catAtt ca LEFT JOIN att a ON ca.attId = a.attId
WHERE ca.catId = 53 AND a.attCatId = 
(
SELECT DISTINCT eav.catId FROM ent LEFT JOIN eav ON ent.entId = eav.entId 
WHERE ent.key = 'somekey'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by simplifying the query.  Both your `left join`s are really inner joins because of the `where` clauses.  Also, the `select distinct` should not be needed in the subquery.

```
select ca.*, att.*
from catAtt ca join
     att a 
     on ca.attId = a.attId 
where ca.catId = 53 and
      a.attCatId = (select eav.catId 
                    from ent join
                         eav 
                         on ent.entId = eav.entId 
                    where ent.key = 'somekey'
                   );
```

This suggests the use of indexes:  `catAtt(catId, attId)`, `att(attId, attCatId)`, `ent(key, entId)`, and `eav(entId, catId)`.

You can also move the subquery in the `where` to the `from`.  I don't think that will have much impact on performance.  It is not correlated, so it is run once, and returns a single value.

Comment: Ok, thank you for pointing that inner join and left join, I been using the left join unnecessarily forgetting the purpose of it. So I think there is no way to make the query into one single query then. Thanks. I would mark this as the answer for correcting the flaw.

Answer (score 1):

I ve tried three type of queries on sql server.

```
SELECT * from catAtt ca JOIN att a ON ca.attId = a.attId
WHERE ca.catId = 53 AND a.attCatId = 
(
SELECT DISTINCT eav.catId FROM ent LEFT JOIN eav ON ent.entId = eav.entId 
WHERE ent.key = 'somekey'
)

SELECT * from catAtt ca 
JOIN att a ON ca.attId = a.attId
JOIN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT eav.catId FROM ent 
  LEFT JOIN eav ON ent.entId = eav.entId 
  WHERE ent.key = 'somekey'
)Z ON a.attCatId = Z.catId 
WHERE ca.catId = 53 

SELECT * from catAtt ca JOIN att a ON ca.attId = a.attId
WHERE ca.catId = 53 AND 
EXISTS 
   (
    SELECT 1 FROM ent LEFT JOIN eav ON ent.entId = eav.entId 
    WHERE ent.key = 'somekey' AND a.attCatId = eav.catId
   )
```

And the query cost for every query is the same 33%.

Guess the DataBase is smarter than we are.

Comment: Interesting that even the 3rd query has "Distinct Sort" in the exec plan.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from catAtt ca 
LEFT JOIN att a ON ca.attId = a.attId
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT eav.catId FROM ent 
  LEFT JOIN eav ON ent.entId = eav.entId 
  WHERE ent.key = 'somekey'
)Z ON a.attCatId = Z.catId 
WHERE ca.catId = 53
```

Try above code.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Did you check the indexes? The presence of indexes has for more impact on the performance than the order of the joins or subqueries. The database engine often reorders joins and subqueries to optimize performance, but it cannot optimize anything if a required index is missing.